# How priority queue and heap are similar?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, heap, heaps-algorithm

How priority queues and heap are similar? i can not find any similarities.
I am looking for the exact answer but could not find anywhere.

Comment: I did a google search for your exact heading for this question and got plenty of good results. Please don't just ask for a difference. Write out what you've learnt from your efforts to understand and then ask us a specific question as to where you're stuck.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: My exact question is how priority queue and heap are similar ? not the differences?

Comment: Isn't "similar" the kind of the opposite of "different"? So if you have the differences, then everything not listed should be similar?